# Profile screen mockup : Is it better to put logout link under user name or at top-right corner?

Tags: mobile, ios, app

See my mockup:

[image]

1) Is this good? Or is it better to put the Logout button at the top bar at upper-right corner? For the lower half of the screen, there's other data and stats I need to put.

2) Also, if I need to let the user adjust Settings for the App, should I put the Settings icon next to the user avatar below? Or should the Settings button be placed at the top right corner of the mobile app? (same row as the Back and Profile text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top nav bar are prime screen estate and is usually reserved for:

- Getting your way around
- Easily accessible commands such as action, cancel, submit, add etc

I prefer not to put my log out button at the top right corner. Providing users with an easily accessible log out button is generally not a good idea. You are showing them the "exit" before they get a chance to explore your app. That being said, you shouldn't make it difficult for the user to log out if they wished to.

In my opinion, the settings would be better fit for the top right location. Here you could also use an icon to utilise a smaller screen area for the link. You might want to put your log out button in the settings page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK1cxA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Wow, ok, tks a lot! Never thought about the "show them the exit" thing before. :-)